# Pronouncing x in the name of a CD product

Tags: pronunciation

I would like to know how to pronounce 48x Cd-Rw. The problem is how to pronounce the "x" in the context of computing.

Answer (score 13):

In my experience, a "*48x CD-RW drive*" is read out either as a "*forty eight **speed** rewritable drive*" or as a "*forty eight **ex** rewritable drive*". The former is the [preferred option](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cys_7DKfjeY) (random video from Lite-On). The latter is more colloquial.

Comment: As a long-time computer geek I say "yes:" `x` is pronounced `speed`.

Answer (score 11):

The symbol x is pronounced *times* there and in a number of other contexts as well. You can remember this by thinking of arithmetic: `2 x 3 = 6` is pronounced *two times three equals six*. The CD packaging is telling you it is 48 times as fast as some long-ago "normal" speed. Specifically:

> CD-ROM drives are rated with a speed factor relative to music CDs (1×
>   or 1-speed which gives a data transfer rate of 150 KiB/s). 12× drives
>   were common beginning in early 1997.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD_Rom

Notice how the wikipedia article carefully uses an x symbol that floats a little higher than the letter you can type on your keyboard. In a book I wrote recently with a lot of need to write about "a 20 times speedup" and the like, we got our copy editors to substitute that "times" symbol for the letter x. But on a product label you would probably not notice the difference.

If you did say *forty-eight ecks* people would probably understand you though.

Comment: I and everyone I know would say "48 *eks*" when referring to a technology product for which *x* meant some multiple of a performance stat.

Comment: Speaking in my geekly capacity, I have never heard it pronounced anything other than "eks".  (48x CD-ROM, 2x compression, etc.)

Comment: Definitely _times_ or _ecks_. Rarely, if ever, _speed_.

Comment: Agree with @Hellion. Definitely *always* "eks". If someone says "forty-eight times" I would know what they meant but assume they are non-technical.

Comment: @Hellion I'm a geek too, and I've heard it called _speed_ and _times_ in equal measure and hardly ever _ecks_. **shrugs** I'd probably opt for _speed_, although in your example: 48 _speed_ CD-ROM, 2 _times_ compression.

Comment: Are you guys saying "eks" all Americans by any chance?? In my UK-based experience, I would expect to hear people say "48 *times*".

Comment: @nohat people quite often think I'm non-technical. **At first**. :-)

Comment: I know this is an english Q&A, but in french, I always only heard "xis" which match your "eks". I never heard someone says "48 fois (times)". So for someone who is not native in english and that will hear someone says something else than 48 "eks", it might be confusing.

Comment: American professional programmer here, I cannot recall ever hearing "eks". I always say "times" myself. Cognitive bias? speed, though, that strikes me as funny.

Comment: Saying "16 eks" seems like saying "16 gee bee(s)" instead of "16 gig(abyte)(s)".

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis, that's funny. American professional programmer here too. While I also cannot ever recall hearing "eks" (thought I would understand it if someone said it), I'm the opposite in the other regard: I and everyone I've ever known have always said "speed" as in "48 speed cd-rom". If I heard someone say "48 times cd-rom", it would strike me as simply wrong (it would sound so wrong, in fact, that I was going to downvote this answer until I realized other people were confirming it in the comments). Maybe it's a regional thing? I'm East Coast.

Comment: @BenLee I'm in Connecticut. The guys over in support I asked in my TOTALLY SCIENTIFIC POLL all said "eks", so, what do I know....